# PHP syntax for static attribute of attribute

Tags: php, syntax, static, attributes

I have implemented a singleton pattern class, and who can be used in another classes like this :

```
class myClass {

private $attr;

public function __construct() {

    $this->attr = Singleton::getInstance;

    echo $this->attr::$sngtAttr; // Throw an error

        // witch syntax use whithout pass by a temp var ? 

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is $sngtAttr a static property?

If not, then just:

`echo $this->attr->sngtAttr; instead of echo $this->attr::$sngtAttr;`

will do it.

Otherwise since is static:

`echo Singleton::$sngtAttr;`

Comment: Hum... What's happen in my head sometime ? 

Thank's, and sorry.

Answer (score 0):

What is your question exactly ?
This is how you do a singleton :

```
<?php

class ASingletonClass
{
    // Class unique instance. You can put it as a static class member if
    // if you need to use it somewhere else than in yout getInstance
    // method, and if not, you can just put it as a static variable in
    // the getInstance method.
    protected static $instance;

    // Constructor has to be protected so child classes don't get a new
    // default constructor which would automatically be public.
    protected final function __construct() 
    {
        // ...
    }

    public static function getInstance() 
    {
        if( ! isset(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    // OR :

    public static function getInstance() 
    {
        static $instance;

        if( ! isset($instance)) {
            $instance = new self;
        }

        return $instance;

        // In that case you can delete the static member $instance.
    }

    public function __clone()
    {
        trigger_error('Cloning a singleton is not allowed.', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}

?>
```

Also don't forget the () when you call getInstance, it's a method, not a member.

Comment: I now I now...Twisted solved it, how did I do to not thinking to echo Singleton::$sngtAttr;